# how to make screenfetch appear automatically

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Im trying to make screenfetch command execute automatically.

I opened bash file using

```
nano~/.bash_profile
```

typed screenfetch in , pressed ctrl O , ctrl X , clear .

when I typed `source nano~/.bash_profile` in terminal
it worked , it actually did what screenfetch is supposed to do. But when I closed terminal and opened it again, it didn't execute screenfetch command automatically. It is saved in bash_profile so it should be executed automatically. Where did I do  a mistake?

Comment: You named the file `.bash_profile` or `nano~/.bash_profile`? What is screenfetch?

Comment: i opened it with nano text edtitor using  nano~/.bash_profile

Comment: `nano~/.bash_profile` is not a valid command; `nano ~/.bash_profile` is, and would create a file named `~/.bash_profile`, but your `source` command is opening a file named `nano~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your command in the `.bashrc` file.

Bash uses this file every time you launch the shell and that is were you define commands that you want to persist between sessions.

Look at *[this question on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work)* for a more in-depth explanation.